# Localize Type Validation in asp.net MVC3 + Razor

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, razor, localization

I'm using asp.net MVC 3 with razor view engine on my app.

What happens is, for example when my model has a date field and someone writes something that is not a valid date o get a message like "The value 'asd' is not valid for StartDate",

I don't know how to localize this message for example to get it on Portuguese "Data inálida".

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

You must set the right attributes on your Model class. Like this:

```
[Date(ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredStar", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
[Required(AllowEmptyStrings = false, ErrorMessageResourceName = "RequiredStar", ErrorMessageResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
[DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
[Display(Name = "Birthday", ResourceType = typeof(Properties.Resources))]
[UIHint("Date")]
public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
```

Comment: Cant find Your Date attribute!

Comment: Do you have nuget? Download the extra DataAnnotation attributes as nuget package. Look for package DataAnnotationsExtensions and DataAnnotationsExtensions.MVC3. Project page: http://dataannotationsextensions.org/

Comment: If the solution worked, don't forget to mark the post as answer.